# All inflated TableRows with same TextView values?

Tags: android, while-loop, layout-inflater

During runtime a user populates a SQLite database.

When a user opens a certain activity in its onCreate method i populate the TableLayout.
I do this using a While loop. All the rows that I inflate in the TableLayout have the same data inside the TextViews. Do I have to add to all the TableRows and TextViwes diferent id's ?

I think if I add "false" when creating the View should fix my problem but it doesnt.

```
View tr = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_chronology, null,false);
```

I think the problem is in my code. If not I'll have to take a better look what happens when the user adds data to the database.

Here is my code for populating TableLayout :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TableLayout tableChronology = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MyDatabase myDB = new MyDatabase(this);
    try {
        myDB.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> historyList = myDB.getHistory();
    Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> iterator = historyList.iterator();
    HashMap<String,String> oneRowMap;
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Add and inflate table rows while there is data
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    oneRowMap = (HashMap<String,String>) iterator.next();

        View tr = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_chronology, null,false);

        tableChronology = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTable);

        String productName = oneRowMap.get("ProductName");
        String calories = oneRowMap.get("Calories");
        String protein = oneRowMap.get("Protein");
        String carbohydrates = oneRowMap.get("Carbohydrates");
        String fats = oneRowMap.get("Fats");
        String grams = oneRowMap.get("Grams");
        //date = oneRowMap.get("Date");

        TextView tv_productName = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.textView_name_show);
        TextView tv_calories = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.textView_kcal_show);
        TextView tv_protein = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.textView_protein_show);
        TextView tv_carbohydrates = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.textView_carbohydrates_show);
        TextView tv_fats = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.textView_fats_show);
        TextView tv_grams = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.textView_grams_show);

        tv_productName.setText(productName);
        tv_calories.setText(calories);
        tv_protein.setText(protein);
        tv_carbohydrates.setText(carbohydrates);
        tv_fats.setText(fats);
        tv_grams.setText(grams);

        tableChronology.addView(tr);

        Toast.makeText(Today.this, "Беше добавен продукт", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        myDB.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: it seems my code above is OK it works fine.
The problem was in my method that retrieves an `ArrayList` full with `HashMap`s:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> historyList = myDB.getHistory();
```

Here is the main code of the method:

```
getHistory():

    do {
        historyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                
        historyMap.put("NumberId", myCursor.getString(0));
        historyMap.put("ProductName", myCursor.getString(1));
        historyMap.put("Calories", myCursor.getString(2));
        historyMap.put("Protein", myCursor.getString(3));
        historyMap.put("Carbohydrates", myCursor.getString(4));
        historyMap.put("Fats", myCursor.getString(5));
        historyMap.put("Grams", myCursor.getString(6));
        // historyMap.put("Date", myCursor.getString(7));

        historyArray.add(historyMap);

    } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
```

It seems I have placed the creation of the `HashMap` outside of the loop and I was passing the same object to the `.add()` method.

Therefore I was populating the `ArrayList` with the same object over and over again.

```
historyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```